# Expectation of a product of discrete r.v.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X∼Geom(1/3)$. Let $Y$ be another random variable which has $Binomial(N,1/4)$ distribution where $N$ is the value taken by the random variable $X$ .

Using the law of total probability, or otherwise, compute the expectation value of the product $XY$.

The book proposes the solution $E(XY) = Σ(N E(Y|X=N)P(X=N))$ .Can someone explain why? I can't understand the N factor inside the sum. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$E[XY] = E[E[XY|X=N]] = \sum E[XY|X=N]P(X=N) = \sum N E[Y|N]P(X=N)$

The third equality is from using the usual definition of an expectation. The outer expectation is on $X$, and the inner is on $Y$ with $X$ taking the value $N$.

The final equality comes from using $X=N$ on the inner expectation, and using linearity of expected value.

Comment: Oh I see now, I don't think we've been taught the first equality in this particular module though... but this is valid for every X, Y, right?

Comment: Yes, it is called the total law of expectation, or the tower rule. It is a really useful result!

Another example:
$X_i$ are insurance claim amounts (iid), and $N$ is a random variable number of claims. Set $S = \sum_{i=0}^N X_i$.

Find $E[S]$

Answer: $E[S] = E[E[S|N]] = E[NE[X_1]] = E[X_1]E[N]$

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!